# Logitech G HUB guessing numbers macro?

Tags: mouse, logitech-gaming-software

Does anyone here know how to make a macro that can guess numbers? more specifically 5 numbers

For example: I play a game that when I click on a **certain thing** 6 numbers appear and instead of typing them I would like the macro to do it for me, to be faster (whenever I click on this **certain thing** the numbers change, that is they are always random numbers whenever I click on the **certain thing**)

That is, let's pretend that when I click on this **certain thing** the numbers generated are 492103 instead of typing them the macro does that for me
After 10 minutes, for example, I click on this **certain thing** again and the numbers generated this time are 941032 and again I would like the macro to type them for me, thus being faster

I just want to make sure you understand that the numbers are always random

I don't know if I'm making myself understood
Thank you for your attention

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-TtTeOrzXo&ab_channel=DiogoPereira - this 7 seconds video explains better what I'm trying to get from the macro

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Lua macro in GHub
Every time you press Middle Mouse Button GHub simulates pressing randomly 6 digit keys

```lua
local seed = 0
for c in GetDate():gmatch"." do
    seed = (seed * 3456781 + c:byte()) % 2^30
end
math.randomseed(seed)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then  -- 3 = Middle Mouse Button
        for i = 1, 6 do
           PressAndReleaseKey(tostring(math.random(10)-1))
           Sleep(10)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think its not something like that, I managed to record a video to show you better what I'm seeking for

And its 5 numbers instead of 6, my bad

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-TtTeOrzXo&ab_channel=DiogoPereira

Comment: If you want to solve a captcha, then it is impossible using GHub.  GHub is unable to view your monitor.

Comment: Is it possible in another way?

Comment: You can write an application (exe file) which does the job of solving captcha, and GHub will only invoke your exe file and simulate key press.